# git: why are push progress messages often counter-intuitive and unhelpful?

Tags: git

OK admittedly I'm not a git expert and the title is a little provocative.
I've worked for years with cvs and subversion but I don't want to go there - I totally get the enormous advantages git has.
I'm just wondering why it can't print more helpful and understandable log messages.
Or maybe it can if configured to do so?
Here an example - I'm in the middle of a large cloned repository.
I have simply added one new file and committed it to the local repository.
Now I do a push to the remote, and I would personally find it useful and reassuring to see what files and/or changes are really being pushed, or at least the number of files.
What do I get? This:

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 24, done.
Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 2.37 KiB | 186.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for develop:
remote:   https://stash.xyz.abc.com:8081/projects/MYPROJ/repos/myrepo-test/pull-requests?create&sourceBranch=refs/heads/develop
remote:
To ssh://stash.xyz.abc.com:7999/MYPROJ/myrepo-test.git
   0478a6e..ea06dc4  develop -> develop
```

Admittedly I don't understand exactly a lot of that, but it seems to me to be more to do with the internal workings of git and maybe performance data. Except the pull request, that's clear. Is there anything there that I could interpret to see that really only one file has been pushed? OK maybe I'm outing myself as stupid or not geeky enough or something but as a developer that's what interests me most and I have to say cvs and svn were clearer there!
I realise I can probably do a git diff beforehand or maybe a dry run or something, but would it really hurt for git to just show what logical operations it is performing in such situations?

Comment: It is giving you the single most important piece of information: the revision where the remote branch _was_ and the new revision it is starting to point to (the one you just pushed): `0478a6e..ea06dc4`. So, what files were modified between them? Well, that's easy to find out, if that's what you care about: `git diff --name-status 0478a6e..ea06dc4`. The important thing to keep in mind is that git does not work (for pushing/fetching) in terms of _files_. It works on **revisions**.

Comment: And if you wanted to know what is different between your branch and the remote branch _before_ the fact: `git fetch origin; git diff --name-status origin/develop develop; git diff --name-status origin/develop...develop` (notice it's 3 dots in the last command, not 2). And then you could run a normal diff (without `--name-status` if you wanted to check the differences and not just the list of files that changed).

Comment: I updated your title because "log messages" refers to the stuff users enter as a log message per commit. (You might want to edit the question body to match.) You're referring to `git push` progress messages here. Note that `git fetch` prints similar progress messages.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things Git is telling you here.  The first four lines, up to “Writing objects,” are progress messages that are intended to tell you that something is happening.  If Git did not print these messages, users would wonder what was taking so long.

The line after that tells you how much stuff was pushed.  In this case, 13 objects were pushed, and two of them were in delta form (that is, they could be compressed).

Those objects will generally include commits and trees as well as the blobs that represent files.  Since Git doesn't duplicate files whose values have been seen before, but it does take a full snapshot of the entire repository at each commit, it's not generally very helpful to say that a certain number of files have changed.  For example, if you make a change, push it, revert it, and then push the revert, you will have made a logical change to the files, but Git will not push any blobs the second time, since the remote side will already have them.

When you perform a checkin for CVS or SVN, you're adding a single revision and so it makes logical sense to say how many files were changed because that is a statement you can make about a single revision.  However, in Git's case, you may be pushing many, many revisions, most of which will contain many identical files, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about the number of files changed.  It's also not a particularly efficient question to answer here because in many cases you can totally omit computing that information.

The final lines tell you what branches are being updated from what to what.  This is information that you can feed to `git diff` or `git log` to see what changed.  When you do a `git pull`, Git does a summary of the changes, but with a push, you may push multiple branches at once, so it doesn't intrinsically make sense to show a summary.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the up-front stuff is just to make users feel good (that progress is occurring).  When you push something very small like this, it doesn't really help at all, but for large push or fetch operations, people seem to get impatient if Git doesn't print progress indicators.

You can turn off the progress indicators with `--no-progress` or `-q` (quiet), if you like.

Let's go through these, line-by-line:

> ```
> $ git push
> ```

(this of course is just your own command)

> ```
> Enumerating objects: 24, done.
> ```

As you surmised, this is showing some internals.  Git has counted 24 *objects*, where an object is a Git internal object: a commit, or a *tree* object (tree objects contain file names and other such information), or a *blob* object (file contents).  There's a fourth kind of object, the *annotated tag*, but since you are not pushing any tags here, the 24 objects that Git counted won't include any of these.

> Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.

This is pretty redundant, but in a big push or fetch, it's useful as a progress meter to feel like things are moving.

> ```
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads
> ```

This tells you that Git thinks that using four CPUs in parallel will speed things up.  You probably have either 4 CPUs, or 2 CPUs each of which does 2 threads.

> ```
> Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
> ```

This is a way of reducing the amount of network data sent.  Some objects can be compressed, and some can't: in your case 7 out of the 24 seemed potentially compress-able.  Git scanned through those 7.

> ```
> Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 2.37 KiB | 186.00 KiB/s, done.
> ```

24 minus 9 = 13, so 9 objects were already present at the other end and 7 of the 13 (about half) were considered for compression.

> ```
> Total 13 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
> ```

This means your Git sent 13 objects total, 2 of which actually *used* compression.  If the other end had some objects that could be used for the compression, the last two numbers might not be zero, but in this case they weren't.

> ```
> remote:
> remote: Create pull request for develop:
> remote:   https://stash.xyz.abc.com:8081/projects/MYPROJ/repos/myrepo-test/pull-requests?create&sourceBranch=refs/heads/develop
> remote:
> ```

**None of these four lines are from *Git*.**  All four were generated by some script at the other end.  Git simply copied them through.  That's what the `remote:` prefix means.  This is probably the most important thing to know, from this answer!

> ```
> To ssh://stash.xyz.abc.com:7999/MYPROJ/myrepo-test.git
> ```

This is just showing where things went, and ...

> ```
>    0478a6e..ea06dc4  develop -> develop
> ```

... this is the most useful line from *Git:* it tells you that you sent the commits that will be listed by:

```
git log 0478a6e..ea06dc4
```

You sent commit `ea06dc4` because you used the name `develop` locally—that's the `develop ->` part—and your Git asked their Git to set *their* name `develop`.  They accepted this request to update their name `develop`: that's the `-> develop` part.  ***Their*** name `develop` *used to* mean commit `0478a6e` (the left side of the two dots), and now means `ea06dc4` (the right side of the two dots).

The reason I put "their" (from "their name") in bold-italic is that they have *their own* `develop` branch, independent of your `develop` branch.  What you and they share are the *commits:* the things with the big ugly hash ID names, such as whatever `ea06dc4` is short for.  CVS and SVN are centralized version control systems, and hence have only one set of names, all stored on the (singular) server.  Git is distributed, so every Git repository has every file stored in every commit, and each Git is its own "server", as it were, with its own set of names.  Your own Git is a peer of any other Git: no one Git is "more equal" than another.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the fantastic answers and explanations! That is a lot of stuff to look into and try and understand fully. I guess I have been using git as a black box, just a place to save my code. So great that people invested so much time to explain fully :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I would personally find it useful and reassuring to see what files and/or changes are really being pushed

If you want to see what's *going to be* pushed, add the `--dry-run` parameter, that will list the ref updates that will be done (or asked for, anyway, the remote can vet your pushed history).

```
$ git push --dry-run ../git2/  make:master
To ../git2/
   274b9cc253..ecff013539  make -> master
$
```

and that's the old and new tips from pushing `make` onto `master` here, master is 274b and will be ecff when you push. Just a note: there can be any number of commits between those two tips.

In the garden-variety cases you already have both the old and new history locally, and you can display whatever parts of it you like as usual, with `git log` or `gitk` or what have you. Push's job is to transmit a pack of history. There's other tools for displaying history nicely. And in many not-so-unusual cases you won't even have the current remote tip at all, displaying it would involve a lot of extra work and traffic. Yuck.

So if you want to preflight what a push is going to do (not knocking the desire, it's not often I want to see it because I already know, but I've done it, it's useful), add `--dry-run` and if you *really* want to lock down what's going to happen you can fetch, dry-run, inspect as needed, then force-with-lease.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I do a push to the remote, and I would personally find it useful and reassuring to see what files and/or changes are really being pushed, or at least the number of files.

That's easy: all of them. Git doesn't traffic in files or changes; it traffics in *commits*. Git will send all the commits reachable from your starting place (typically a branch name) that the remote doesn't already have, and every one of those is a *complete* snapshot of your project.

So if for example you are about to push master and you want to get an idea what's in it, look in the `master` commit, e.g. with `ls-tree`:

```
git ls-tree -r master
```

Those are the "files" that are about to be "pushed" (in their most recent form; if more commits are being pushed, other versions of some files will also be pushed).

Or if what you really want to know is what the "changes" are, do a `git fetch` to bring your remote-tracking branch up to date, and now just `git diff` your `master` against its remote-tracking branch, typically `origin/master`. If all you want is the changed file count, add the `--shortstat` option.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers explain what git's output is in detail. However, you can also add your own output (or do other stuff) by setting up the [`pre-push` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) in `.git/hooks`. The following hook lists file differences between the revision your remote branch is pointing at, and the one you're about to push.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

remote="$1"
url="$2"

while read local_ref local_oid remote_ref remote_oid
do
    echo "Pushing local $local_ref to $remote's $remote_ref:"
    git diff --stat $remote_oid $local_oid
done
```

Sample output (Git au fromage free of charge):

```
$ git push origin master
Pushing local refs/heads/master to origin's refs/heads/master:
 test | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
Énumération des objets: 5, fait.
Décompte des objets: 100% (5/5), fait.
Écriture des objets: 100% (3/3), 236 octets | 236.00 Kio/s, fait.
Total 3 (delta 0), réutilisés 0 (delta 0), réutilisés du pack 0
To <git host>/test-repo.git
   3bb790c..5f22c87  master -> master
```

Comment: One caveat: the `$remote_oid` hash ID might specify a commit that is *not in your repository*. (This presents a problem, both for your answer and mine, where I suggest running `git log` on the two-dot-separated hash IDs. However, if you're not using `git push --force` or one of the other force flags, the push itself would fail in this case. So for my answer you'd never get a chance to run the `git log` command in the first place. :-) In a pre-push hook, the `git diff` would fail with a complaint about the hash ID not being resolveable.)